# Changing Display Text in Rally AttributeComboBox (SDK 2.0p)

Tags: rally

I'm having an issue setting the display text for an AttributeComboBox on Rally (SDK 2.0p, not the newer versions). Currently, the AttributeComboBox generates a list of the URL address for each owner within the current project, but not the name of each owner. I thought setting displayField to 'Owner.Name' or something similar would work, but it hasn't. Here is my following code (Javascript):

`this.down('#ownerFilter').add({

    xtype: 'rallyattributecombobox',

    cls: 'filter',

    model: 'UserStory',

    field: 'Owner',

    displayField: 'Owner',

    valueField: 'Owner',

    allowBlank: false,

    listeners: {

        ready: this._onOwnerComboBoxLoad,

        select: this._onOwnerComboBoxSelect,

        scope: this

        }

    });`

(Note: Sample code has been changed. Attribute has been changed from "iteration" to "owner".)

Instead of having my AttributeComboBox generate a list of URL addresses (which do correspond to the owners within the current project), how do I make the names of the owners appear instead?

I feel like the answer is extremely simple, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the AttributeComboBox rather than the IterationComboBox?  IterationComboBox will show the name and the dates...

Comment: Hi Kyle,

I guess using "iteration" as the attribute was a bad choice here. I also have other combo boxes for other attributes (such as "owner") in which I would like to display a list of user names (instead of as URL addresses).

Answer (score 0):

It'd be nice if you could format your code for readability. In any case, You are already specifying the field "Iteration" on the model "UserStory". I believe the displayField could just be set to "Name," since it is already operating on "Iteration".

Comment: Sorry about that. Code has been formatted for readability. I tried changing displayField to "Name", but it is still displaying the URL address pertaining to each iteration.

Comment: Have you already tried specifying the "displayName" in the "listConfig" ?

Comment: That would be something along the lines of "listConfig { displayName: 'Name' }", correct? Unfortunately, that didn't work either.